# Github Actions + docker-compose gives "No such file or directory"

Tags: docker, rust, docker-compose, github-actions

I am writing CI for Github Actions with Rust. I want to execute `docker-compose` from Rust for some reasons. Within the `Command`, I am specifying a current working dir in the folder where the docker-compose.yml is located. This is some code:

```
let docker_compose_file = current_dir.parent().unwrap().to_owned();

if docker_compose_file.join("docker-compose.yml").exists() {
    println!(
        "Found docker-compose file, full path: {:#?}",
        docker_compose_file
    );

    // DEBUG CODE
    let ls_result = Command::new("ls")
        .arg(docker_compose_file.to_str().unwrap())
        .output()
        .unwrap()
        .stdout;

    let y = String::from_utf8(ls_result).unwrap();

    println!("LS'ing gives: {:#?}", y);
} else {
    panic!(
        "Wrong file, current working dir: {:#?}",
        docker_compose_file
    );
}

let result = Command::new("docker-compose")
    .current_dir(&docker_compose_file)
    .args(&["up", "-d"])
    .status()
    .unwrap();
```

I see in the Github Actions the following logging:

> Found docker-compose file, full path:
> "/Users/runner/work/something/something/server"
> LS'ing gives:
> "Cargo.lock\nCargo.toml\napi\nbatch_jobs\nci_setup\ncommon\ndatabase\ndeployment.md\ndocker-compose.yml\nrustfmt.toml\nserver\ntarget\n"
> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err`
> value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or
> directory" }', ci_setup/src/main.rs:137:14 note: run with
> `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

I am confused. `ls` clearly shows me the docker-compose.yml file is present. Why do I get the Rust error, saying it can not find the file or directory?

main.rs:137 refers to the `unwrap` method call at the bottom of the code example.

Comment: Could you share the GHA workflow (.yml file) used on your question? 

Comment: @GuiFalourd it's not really that special, I clone my project in a dir, I `cd` to that dir and run `cargo run`

Comment: I asked this because to access repository files in a GHA workflow, you need to use the `actions/checkout`. If you didn't use it, it might be the origin of your problem.